# Execute an extension-less file as PHP

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I've looked through a lot of questions, but only seem to find solutions so that the user sees, for example, `http://www.example.com/page` but the file name is `http://www.example.com/page.php`.

What I'm looking for, is a way to have a file actually called `http://www.example.com/page` (not `page.php`) that the server executed as a regular PHP file.

Would that be possible? (If so, I think it's probably done in the .htaccess file somehow, but I'm not sure.)

---

## EDIT

So, I'm trying to make a website that only uses one file to show multiple pages and `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']` to know which to show. To make it look better, I tried overwriting the shown URL so that the user sees `.../page` instead of `.../page.php`, but it somehow didn't recognize the path info when accessing the rewritten page. (Not sure if this makes sense, tried my best to explain.)

Comment: If the file doesn't have any file extension, how would the server now how to parse it? I'm guessing you have a reason for wanting to do this, could you share it?

Comment: This might be possible, though very questionable. Have a try with the combination of the two commands `AddType` and `ForceType`, you can do that in an .htaccess style file, if you really have to. Just take a look at the documentation: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_mime.html#addtype http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#forcetype

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Edited

Comment: Sounds like you need a Router. Google for "php router" or search for "router" on packagist.org. There are simple, small once that work fine but wit limited features and more complex once with a lot of features.

Answer (score 2):

You can use that in your `.htaccess`:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on 

# skip all files and directories from rewrite rules below
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# add php if possible
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]

# rewrite other to index.php file
RewriteRule ^ /index.php [L]
```

and you can use `index.php` to show multiple pages (without existing file).

If `test.php` exist, you can use it with `http://www.exemple.com/test`
but if `test.php` does not exist that show `index.php` which show your content for this page.

Comment: Works perfectly on apache 2.4. Thanks!